# Changing inline listings font size when inside a footnote

Tags: listings, footnotes

Listings will have the same size specified on `basicstyle`, which i've set to `footnotesize`, which looks best for my purposes. However, that also applies to inline listings, which usually happen on normal text, and so, should be normal sized.

One can change that with `\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle\normalsize}`. However, that makes so that inline listings inside footnotes are also are normal sized. I want to change that behaviour so that the size automatically changes to `\footnotesize` when inside a footnote.

This is my best attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{listings, letltxmacro}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont
}

% Making so \lstinline has the same size as normal text
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle\normalsize\ttfamily\selectfont}
\makeatother

% Setting the correct size on footnote
\LetLtxMacro{\OldFootnote}{\footnote}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnote}[2][\value{footnote}]{ %
    \lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle\footnotesize}% Setting size of lslinline to footnote
    \OldFootnote[{#1}]{#2}%
    \lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle\normalsize}% Setting size of lslinline to normal
    \relax%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Sample text\footnote{Sample footnote with \lstinline|inline_listings| embedded with footnote size.} with normal size \lstinline|inline_listings|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

This solution has 3 problems:

- All the footnotes start with a 0.
- There's always a space between the word and the footnote symbol, even when there's no space between the word and `\footnote` in the code.
- It seems a bit "hacky". It feels like using `\lst@AddToHook` every time you use a footnote would hog the compiler if you have a long file with a lot of footnotes.

So my question is: Is there a more elegant or "correct" solution for this? If not, how do I solve those first 2 problems?

Comment: I did some experiment myself, and it seems like inline listing in footnote is already of footnote size.

Comment: @AlanXiang You are indeed correct. The problem only happens when you modify the size on `basicstyle`. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest strategy is to define a command on top of `\lstinline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily
}
\newcommand{\code}[1][]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1]}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}

Sample text

\begin{lstlisting}
This is footnote size
\end{lstlisting}

Sample text\footnote{Sample footnote with \code|inline_listings| embedded 
with footnote size.} with normal size \code|inline_listings|.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution would end up setting the size of normal listings to `0.9\normalsize`, however, the objective is for them to be `\footnotesize`, (or any other arbitrary size, not dependent on the current `\fontsize`)

Comment: @LuizMartins Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Now it should be how you want it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that doesn't use a new command is simply resetting the font size of inline listings using `\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}`, since when they don't have a specific font size, they adapt to the current one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily
}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle\ttfamily}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}

Sample text

\begin{lstlisting}
This is footnote size
\end{lstlisting}

Sample text\footnote{Sample footnote with \lstinline|inline_listings| embedded with footnote size.} with normal size \lstinline|inline_listings|.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]